# how can i predict future days' temperature values?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, prediction, weather

hope you are fine i am basically new in machine learning and i need help from you guys. I want to predict next 3 days temperature values hourly how can i do that ? Can anyone help....??

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn import metrics
dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saadh\Desktop\The Weather Forecast\Rawalpindi.csv")
#print(dataset.head)
X = dataset[['moon_illumination','sunHour','date_time','mintempC','uvIndex','DewPointC','humidity','cloudcover','pressure','windspeedKmph']].values
Y = dataset['maxtempC'].values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300, random_state=0)
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictData = regressor.predict(X_test)
#df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': Y_test, 'Predicted': predictData})
#res = df.head()
#print(df)
print(predictData.astype(int))
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(Y_test, predictData))
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, predictData))
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, predictData)))
```

**Output:**
[43 40 41 41 40 40 39]

Mean Absolute Error: 0.5561904761904758
Mean Squared Error: 1.0668126984126995
Root Mean Squared Error: 1.0328662538841606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the features for the values you want to predict and feed them to your trained model.
Like in your code you do a prediction on the test dataset `X_test`, which is a part of the features stored in `X`.

So to do a prediction for other data you need to get the features similar to this line in your code

```
X = dataset[['mintempC','moon_illumination','date_time','uvIndex','sunHour','DewPointC','pressure','humidity','cloudcover']].values
```

and then do the prediction like this

```
predictData = regressor.predict(X)
```

Comment: I didn't get your point can you explain. If i do predictData = regressor.predict(X_test) then in output i have values in form of arrays which are predicted values
Output is :
[38 38 40 41 44 44 40 ...... 41]

Comment: Currently you're doing the prediction for the X_test data. If I understand your question correctly, you now want to do other predictions, right? Then you need to pass other data into your model.

Comment: I want to predict 3 days future temperature hourly. I just want to ask that how i perform this task.... Because in output i have many values and i want to choose for only next 3 days with date and time.

Comment: Ok, so a model makes predictions for the data that you pass into it via regressor.predict(X). In your data X, you have a date_time column. If you want to predict the next 3 days, you look at the dates in that column, choose the next three days from your data, and then pass that into the predict() function of your model. The output will be only the predicted temperature values, without date labels, but it should be in the same order, so you can reassign the dates afterwards.

Comment: How i choose "next three days" because in dataset i have weather information for previous days and time and i want to predict future from previous days value. How i will do that ?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're trying to do. In this case you need another type of model. Have a look at this tutorial, where they use a Recurrent Neural Network to do this type of temperature forecasting: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have one question though: to forecast the data, what exactly to I pass to the model? I know that in ARIMA (and other variants) you can simply define the amount of time steps you want to forecast into the future and it gives you the results. Here what am I exactly feeding to the model? Because if I want to predict next week's occurrences, I won't have, for example, the lagged variables for all the days. I hope the question is clear

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really get your question. Which model are you referring to here: "Here what am I exactly feeding to the model?"?
If you train your model to predict temperatures one week in advance, you don't need data for the days in between now and then.

Comment: my question is that till now i have test outputs but i don't want test outputs i want future predictions for n days let say 3 days in future.
How i will do that ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting your effort. Are my test outputs are final and future predictions ?

Comment: Your outputs depend on the data you put into your model. When you use test data as input you get test outputs, when you use real data you get real predictions. - Let me give you an example: Let's say you have trained a model that predicts temperatures 3 days in the future. Next step is to test it, using your test data. If you're satisified by the results of the test, you can now feed real data into the model. This way you get real predictions.

Comment: Ohhh thanks a lot buddy how stupid i am.... It helped me a lot and thanks again Stay blessed :)